# How can I predict the resources needed to complete SQL request under given DB structure and given table sizes?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, bigdata

I understand that the measurement of the resources needed for any calculation is very relative and depends on:

- hardware configuration,
- software settings,
- methodology after all.

But anyway if I want to develop a web application which using a database I will definitely need to create DB structure intelligently.

Of course there is a theory which can tell us how exactly DB engine work under given circumstances. But I expect that the circumstance list will be too complex: type of storage engine, hardware configuration and so on...

I'd really like to be able to set up an empty DB and find out how many CPU 'ticks', IOs and memory would be used if the affected tables would have the given amount of rows.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

> I'd really like to be able to set up an empty DB and find out how many
>   CPU 'ticks', IOs and memory would be used if the affected tables would
>   have the given amount of rows.

That won't work.

Query optimizers take into account a lot of different things, one of them usually being the number of rows estimated to be returned by the query.  Those estimates will be good only if the number of rows in your tables is about the same as you'd find in production. Otherwise, the optimizer will probably choose a radically different execution plan than you'd get on a production database.

So populate your test db with the number of rows you expect. Build queries that you believe will be a representative sample of what you'd find in production. Run them, and measure what they do.

Comment: What do you mean saying `...measure what they do`? Could you explain a little bit more?

Comment: You were going to measure "CPU 'ticks', IOs and memory". However you intended to do that, then *do* that. You might also record and save the execution plans.

Comment: This is about `EXPLAIN`? Thank you for giving me the right direction. Moreover I found several optimization tuts in the Internet. Hope that I will be able to ask less common questions after that.

Comment: `EXPLAIN` returns the execution plan.